# What's the proper syntax to follow a link using beautifulsoup & requests in a django app?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I asked a question that I don't think I was clear on. I have already succesfuly scraped posts from a sites home page. The next step is to follow the link from the post to it's detail page so I can scrape the details content. This is the code I have tried to modify but it's not working. Mind you I am a novice and I am using this in a django app.

```
def sprinkle():
    url_two = 'http://www.example.com'
    html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

    entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'comment': BeautifulSoup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'}),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                } for div in titles][:6]

    return entries
```

and in my views

```
sp = sprinkle()

context = {
   "comment": sp
}
```

and in my template

```
{% for s in sp %}
   {{s.comment}}
{% endfor %}
```

in the html all it shows is

```
[]
```

the urls I'm trying to scrape look like this

```
http://www.example.com//article/218582/detail-art
http://www.example.com//article/218817/detail-science
http://www.example.com//article/218542/detail-theatre
```

how can I use the links to go to the detail page and scrape the data from that page?

Comment: Can you add the url you are scraping? Also your last question that I answered was about an error so not really related at all to what is happening now. You also realise `BeautifulSoup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'})` returns an empty list?

Comment: Right. That's why I'm on here. To be clear so I don't waist your time. I have scraped some posts that have links. I want to follow those links to the detail page and scrape whatever body content is there.

Comment: yes bit your scraping is not working, you need to sort that before you worry about django. As I said if you share the link it will take me 5 minutes to solve the ssue, without it or the html I don't think anyone can help you

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I edited my question above so you can see the links to the different pages

Comment: but they are not what you are actually scraping? Something is wrong in your code so without seeing the actual html I have no clue at all what is not working.

Comment: What I'm scraping is example.com. thats where the links that I want to follow are coming from

Comment: But there is no div with  `entry-pos-1` so your code finds nothing, hence the empty list

Comment: That works. the only issue is when I add ''comment': BeautifulSoup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'}),' if I remove that it works. Why don't you just tell me how you would do what i'm trying to accomplish since you don't get what i'm doing.

Comment: So `BeautifulSoup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'})` does not return an empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work

```
def sprinkle():
        url_two = 'http://www.vladtv.com'
        html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

        def make_soup(url):
            the_comments_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(the_comments_page.text, 'html5lib')
            comment = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'article-body'})
            para = comment.find_all('p')
            return para

        entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                    'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                    'comments': make_soup(url_two + div.a.get('href'))
                    } for div in titles][:6]

        return entries
```

but the way I solved it the square brackets still show