# How Can I follow A Link to a specific post and scrape the data from the

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to follow links from posts that I have scraped so I can save the text. I am partly there. I just need to tweak some things which is why I'm here. Instead of different posts I am getting duplicates. and not only that, they are surrounded in brackets like this

```
[[<div class="article-body" id="image-description"><p>Kanye West premiered 
        the music video for "Famous" off his "The Life of Pablo" album to a 
        sold out audience in Los Angeles.  The video features nude versions of George W. Bush. 
        Donald Trump. Anna Wintour. Rihanna. Chris Brown. Taylor Swift. 
      Kanye West. Kim Kardashian. Ray J. Amber Rose. Caitlyn Jenner. 
    Bill Cosby (in that order).</p></div>],
```

and heres my code

```
    def sprinkle():
       url_two = 'http://www.example.com'
       html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
       titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

       def make_soup(url):
           the_comments_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
           soupdata = BeautifulSoup(the_comments_page.text, 'html5lib')
           comment = soupdata.find_all('div', {'class': 'article-body'})
           return comment

       comment_links = [url_two + link.a.get('href') for link in titles]

       soup = [make_soup(comments) for comments in comment_links]
           # soup = make_soup(comments)
           # print(soup)

       entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                   'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                   'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                   'comments': soup
                   } for div in titles][:6]

       return entries
```

I feel like I'm close. this is all new to me. Any help would be great.

Comment: They are called lists. If you want what is inside you need to iterate over them and extract what you want, also how is your code so similar to this  users http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022573/whats-the-proper-syntax-to-follow-a-link-using-beautifulsoup-requests-in-a-dj?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out

```
def sprinkle():
        url_two = 'http://www.vladtv.com'
        html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

        def make_soup(url):
            the_comments_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(the_comments_page.text, 'html5lib')
            comment = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'article-body'})
            para = comment.find_all('p')
            return para

        entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                    'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                    'comments': make_soup(url_two + div.a.get('href'))
                    } for div in titles][:6]

        return entries
```

I'm trying to remove the brackets though from the result though